# Spring boot is picking wrong CorsFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot web application with security features. I am relying on a library with a custom Cors Filter that I need to use but my application keeps picking the Spring Web Framework Cors Filter instead and renders the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:run
>   (default-cli) on project tools-services: An exception occurred while
>   running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with
>   name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
>   'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean
>   named 'corsFilter' is expected to be of type
>   'org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter' but was actually of type
>   'com.myproj.sample.inf.sec.filter.CorsFilter' -> [Help 1]

I am trying to create a CorsFilter bean in my Application.java class as such:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    return new CorsFilter();
}
```

However, this gives me the same error. Is there a way to make Spring Boot point to the custom cors filter or disable the spring cors filter?

Answer (score 0):

Probably is because of the same name. Can you try to change bean name used in your Application.java?